# How to convert enumerate objects to set and tuple in python?

Tags: python

How to convert enumerate objects to set and tuple in python?

```
grocery = ['bread', 'milk', 'butter']
enumerateGrocery = enumerate(grocery)
print(type(enumerateGrocery))
print(set(enumerateGrocery)) # returning set()
print(tuple(enumerateGrocery))# returning ()

Excepted output:-
{(0, 'bread'), (1, 'milk'), (2, 'butter')}
((0, 'bread'), (1, 'milk'), (2, 'butter'))
```

Comment: What does 0,1,2 signify?
Counters?

Answer (score 4):

`enumerate` returns an iterator that gets exhausted by the first consumer (which is the `set` constructor). Do for instance:

```
grocery = ['bread', 'milk', 'butter']
enumerateGrocery = enumerate(grocery)  
print(type(enumerateGrocery))

t = tuple(enumerateGrocery)  # tuple first, to maintain order
# now, enumerateGrocery is exhausted (empty)
s = set(t)  # just use the tuple that now contains all the elements
print(s) 
print(t)
```

Comment: @user3663615 one thing that's important to note: if you build the set first (using the iterator directly), you don't guarantee that things are zipped in proper order.

Comment: why enumerateGrocery is exhausted (empty) If I use print(list(enumerateGrocery)) after the statement t = tuple(enumerateGrocery)

Comment: @user3663615 Because all those constructors of iterables (list, set, tuple, etc.) have to iterate the iterables they are given in order to collect all their elements. Therefore, `list(enum...)` consumes and exhausts the iterator as well. You can use such an iterator exactly once, if you want to use its elements mutiple times, store them in a container like a list and use that one: `l = list(enum...); t = tuple(l); s = set(l)`...

Answer (score 0):

The first example output is invalid. Anyway:

```
tuple(((i,v) for i, v in enumerate(grocery)))
```

Or simply

```
tuple(enumerate(grocery))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `enumerate` function is a generator, which means you have to iterate over it to get the items out of it. A fast way to do this is to use a set comprehension like this:

```
grocery = ['bread', 'milk', 'butter']
{(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(grocery)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using the `zip` function:

```
grocery = ['bread', 'milk', 'butter']

grocerySet = set(zip(grocery,range(len(grocery))))
groceryTuple = tuple(zip(grocery,range(len(grocery))))

print(grocerySet)
print(groceryTuple)
```

Output:

```
{('milk', 1), ('butter', 2), ('bread', 0)}
(('bread', 0), ('milk', 1), ('butter', 2))
```